# Date range for jobs & conversions SUMPRODUCT

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date-time

I'm trying to run a report within Excel that shows the total number of jobs completed by employees within a date range and also a count of the number of conversions per employee within the same date range.

My data is as follows:

- Column A: Date  (Range from A1:A100 spanning several years)
- Column B: Employee Name (DAVE is the example employee name)
- Column C: Converted (a simple binary showing 1 or 0 depending if the job has converted)
- Cell D1: has the start date in my range (01/01/2015)
- Cell D2: has the end date in my range (31/12/2015)

I have already worked out the basic count of jobs (in Cell F4)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B100=DAVE)*(A1:A100>=D1)*(A1:A100<=D2))
```

What I need to do is add to this to only count the number of records with this name within the date range but also have a "1" in column C to show the job has converted.

This will appear in Cell G4.

I have attached a screenshot of the example.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Missing screenshot

Comment: Screenshot now attached.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you only need to add that last condition to get Dave's converted jobs:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B100="Dave")*(A1:A100>=D1)*(A1:A100<=D2)*(C1:C100=1))
```